# Provide Custom Chunks Flash Media Server

Tags: video-streaming, flash-media-server

I am trying flash media server to see if it can accomplish a specific task I need to do. I have a Django + OpenCV app which process a video file and outputs the processed video splitted  in 1 second chunks.

I have been exploring Flash Media Server and I found some tags like `<OutChunkSize>` to be used in the Application.xml files to configure the size of the chunks.

I need to know if there is any way of configure the server to stream the chunks over HTTP as they are generated by the Django app instead of allowing the server to split the video itself

EDIT: I read part of the adobe documentation and found that FMS supposedly writes .f4f segments and .f4x index of segments to the disk. Here is the [link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/HTTPStreaming/1.0/Using/WS9463dbe8dbe45c4c-c126f3b1260533756d-7ffc.html). It would be helpful if anyone knows where this files are stored.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're referring to in regards to FMS is HTTP Dynamic Streaming (HDS). The Flash Media Server is working in conjunction with an Apache web server to package the F4F files on the fly and then serve up the segment/fragment files for a specified stream (VOD or Live) and time. The files aren't stored anywhere in this case (they may be cached, but I don't know where).

There is a use case & workflow for files being stored on the server. In this case, the files are packaged using the f4fpackager tool and then are uploaded to the web server.

Adobe Documentation for HDS: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/HTTPStreaming/1.0/Using/index.html